# Google Earth Engine: How can I compare Landsat 8, Landsat 9 and Sentinel 2 surface reflectance?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to compare the SWIR values of L8, L9 and S2. I am using the following collections:

- L8: "LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2" Band 7
- L9: "LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2" Band 7
- S2: "COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED" Band 12

I think that some scaling factor is necessary to compare Landsat and Sentinel as the Landsat values are in the thousands while the Sentinel values are in the hundreds.

For example, GEE suggests using this scaling factor for L9 but then the values are between 0 and 0.3.

```
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}
```

What should I do to compare the values?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to divide the S2 images by 10000. This is mentioned in the `scale` column here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR_HARMONIZED#bands.

For Landsat images you are ok with the `applyScaleFactors` function from https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2 .

Note that since you want to compare Surface Reflectance, you probably want to use `COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED` and not `COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED` which is the level 1 data.